# UnicodeEncodeError при печати имени пользователя

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Работаю с API VK, и хочу получить список Имён пользователя, но почему-то получаю ошибку из-за кодировки. Что бы я ни пробовал — одна и та же проблема...

Код:

```
tst = api.friends.get(user_id=1, fields="nickname")
for i in range(len(tst)):
    print(tst[i]['first_name'])
```

Ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Это проблема не API VK, а консоли Windows, в которой невозможно распечатать данный символ из имени

Comment: Спасибо большое! В графическом интерфейсе все нормально показывает

Comment: @andreymal почему невозможно. Если шрифт настроить и Unicode API используется (Python 3.6 или win-unicode-console), то любой BMP символ можно напечатать, даже вне OEM/ANSI code pages.

Comment: @АфикАлиев сообщения об ошибке старайтесь в виде текста приводить, чтобы ваш вопрос другие люди с той же проблемой могли найти. Если не знаете как текст скопировать из консоли, то задайте отдельный вопрос, если его ещё не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы в консоли Windows установите win-unicode-console.

```
pip install win-unicode-console
```

Далее запускайте следующим образом:

```
python -m run script.py
```